# Strange behaviour printing arguments from safari dev tools

Tags: javascript, android, ios, safari, safari-web-inspector

I'm building an app with ionic.
I've got this function declaration:

```
function calculate(origin, destination, mode, transitOptions, alternatives, onMap) {

  var request = buildRequest(arguments);

  var validationResult = validate(request);
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  .....
```

While debugging with chrome inspector on the android simulator I get this:

[image: correct]

The same call made on the iphone simulator and debugged with safari results in this:

[image: very strange?]

And of course the code breaks. Did anyone ever seen something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this before. It looks like `arguments` is being evaluated on a different call frame than the one where execution is paused. Based on the value of `arguments[1]`, it looks like it is being evaluated in a call frame that's internal to the Web Inspector implementation.

Normally, evaluating on the console while paused will evaluate the expression in the scope of the currently selected call frame. But, in your second screenshot you omitted the Scope Chain sidebar, so I can't really tell what the current call frame is.

It would also help to include version numbers of the software you are running (Safari, iOS Simulator). Are you able to reproduce this issue in a recent [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/) release?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14146554)

Comment: Yes, by all means, downvote the only answer written by the developer of the software in question. Great way to get answers!

I provided as much of an answer as is possible given the OP, but I cannot really know what happened without further information. Given that the OP has not seemed to have read this answer, this is probably the best we will get.

Comment: It wasn't me though

Comment: Sorry I didn't come back to you. The day after I was not able to reproduce again the "error", I tried just now again with "no luck". Thanks for the answer anyway!